# Defining a struct with a pointer

Tags: c

I'm relatively new to C and trying to understand `structs` and `pointers`. What does the `*Building` at the end of this struct declaration do?

```
typedef struct building {
        char *floor;
        struct building *nextBuilding;
} *Building;
```

Does it mean that from now on when I do

```
Building someBuilding = malloc(sizeof(struct building));
```

somebuilding is a pointer to a `building`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you write:

```
 typedef struct building { … } *Building;

 Building bp;
```

then `bp` is a pointer to a `struct building`.  However, it is frequently regarded as bad style to include the pointer in the `typedef`; code is easier to understand if you use:

```
 typedef struct building { … } Building;

 Building *bp;
```

Now it is clear looking at the definition of `bp` that the type is a pointer.  If you are never going to access the internals of the structure, then it doesn't matter too much (but look at `FILE *` in `<stdio.h>`; you always write `FILE *fp`, etc).  If you're going to access the internals:

```
printf("Floor: %s\n", bp->floor);
```

then it is better to have the pointer visible.  People will be mildly surprised to see `Building bp;` and then later `bp->floor` instead of `bp.floor`.

Comment: interseting because my cs professor used *Building in his code. Thanks

Comment: Professors do not have a monopoly on good style.  It is an area where people disagree, but I think you'd find a fair number of people agree with me.  See, for example, [Typedef pointers — a good idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/typedef-pointers-a-good-idea)

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question: yes. You now have a type `Building` that is a pointer to a `struct building` and you can do this:

```
Building someBuilding = malloc(sizeof(struct building));
someBuilding->floor = malloc (sizeof(char)*20);
strcpy(someBuilding->floor, "First floor");
someBuilding->nextBuilding = NULL;
```

etc.

note that this might not be a good idea in all cases. For example if you declare a method:

```
void setFloorName(Building building, char* name)
```

you can't really tell that you need to pass a pointer to a building struct, but if you do:

```
void setFloorName(Building* building, char* name)
```

you immediately see that the function takes a pointer.